# Operator overloading explanation

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, c++14

I am trying to understand an output of a short program where operator overloading is used.

The output is 137, where the `(2+v).print()` outputs **13** and **7** is from `v.print();`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class V
{
    int x;
public:
    V(int a = 7, int b = 3) { x = a + b; }
    void print() { cout << x; }
    V operator+(int n)
    {
        return x++ + ++n;
    }
};

V operator+(int lop, V rop)
{
    return rop + lop;
}

int main()
{
    V v(1, 6);
    (2 + v).print();
    v.print();
    return 0;
}
```

I understand the basic concept of the operator overloading and I get that `V rop` is just a copy of the `V v(1,6)`, and it doesn't change the output of `v.print();` where `x` stays 7, but I don't get why it outputs 13, I always get to 10.

Comment: Hint: `operator+` should be `const`. Also, explain the workings of the operator to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Make the constructor `explicit` to spot the implicit conversion that you're missing.

Comment: I think that I got it just now, that the return x++ + ++n; makes a new V object where the first parameter is the sum of x + ++n (i just ignored the x++ as it doesn't make a difference), so it makes a new instance of V where a = the sum, and b = 3, so it gets 13 as value! Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when trying to return an object of type 'V' from this operator:

```
V operator+(int n)
{
    return x++ + ++n;
}
```

What you're trying to return here in an 'int' so it should be cast to an object of type 'V', **the way it's done (casting from a primitive type to custom class) is using constructors.** The only constructor you're having is with 2 optional parameters which creates the problem that it tries to make an object of one parameter only, so it's sent as a = 10, b = 3 (default value) and then the output is 13.

I recommend using multiple constructors to solve the problem if you don't want to change the members of the class.

```
class V
{
    int x;
public:
    V() { x = 10; }
    V(int a) { x = a; }
    V(int a, int b) { x = a + b; }
    void print() { cout << x; }
    V operator+(int n)
    {
        return x++ + ++n;
    }
};
```

By this way you can call a default constructor which sets x to 10 as you previously did, another constructor with 1 parameter to cast from 'int' to 'V', and your normal constructor that takes a and b.

Answer (score 0):

In your `code` when arrive at `return (x++ + ++n);` compiler create an object `V` so your constructor will be call again. then these assignment will be occurred `a=10` and `b=3`. So you gotta save `a` and `b` values in another `members`.

Try this :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class V {
    int x;
    int a;
    int b;

public:
    V(int a=7, int b=3) { x = a + b; this->a = a; this->b = b; }
    void print() { cout << x - this->b; }
    V operator+(int n) {
    return (x++ + ++n);
    }
};

V operator+(int lop, V rop) {
    return rop + lop;
}
int main()
{
    V v(1,6);
    (2 + v).print();
    v.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Your `(2 + v).print();` output will be `10`.